# facebook post and page insights not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm using Graph API to get statistics from my pages , I created an application and I got my permissions (read_insights , manage_pages ...) , but only some metrics work fine like page_fans_country and most of them (page_fans / post_impressions / page_impressions / page_fans_gender_age ...) don't work and return : [data] => Array () .
I tried 3 different pages , the first have 20.000 likes , the second 3.000 and the third 30 likes , and I can't get any information from them except for page_fans_country . But when I try those previous queries in Graph Api Explorer with its token , it works fine , when I use my token it doesn't work , and i'm sure i have the read_insights permission

Please , Help me .

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer

Change the order of the scope parameter:

Try

```
"email,read_insights,manage_pages"
```

Instead of

```
"email,manage_pages,read_insights"
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For most page insights, you need a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/).

A normal user access token, even one from a page admin, won't return any data.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. 
It seems that I get some insights by prefixing the message fb id with the page id, so instead of hitting `https://graph.facebook.com/messageFbId/insights?access_token=...` (the official docs say to do it), I get the insights from `https://graph.facebook.com/pageId_messageFbId/insights?access_token=....`

Hope this helps